# kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yaml prompts an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-eks

I have created a cluster with a role and created a worker node using CloudFormation. I am trying to grant a user access to the cluster but I try this command `kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yaml` I keep getting this error (minized):

> Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of my IAM user; I didn't change my user Credentials before creating the stack with CloudFormation.

Answer (score 0):

1) please check if you have installed [aws-iam-authenticator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html)

2)when you try to run `kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yaml`, I want you to check first your `~/.aws/credentials` have you ran `aws configure`?

3) run `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster_name>`